# Is there a shorthand for wrapping Generic methods?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

We have a data access library with generic methods like this:

```
public List<T> Find<T>(
    List<DataObject> conditions,
    Boolean fuzzy = false,
    String order = null,
    Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
    T start = null) where T : DataObject, new()
{
    ... 
}

// special case of Find()
public List<T> Find<T>(
    DataObject condition,
    Boolean fuzzy = false,
    String order = null,
    Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
    T start = null) where T : DataObject, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Our business objects then routinely to be endowed with a handful of `Get()` methods like this:

```
public static MyClass Get(Guid id)
{
    List<MyClass> possibles = Get(new MyClass() { Id = id });
    if (possibles.Count == 1)
    {
        return possibles[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static List<MyClass> Get(
    MyClass condition,
    Boolean fuzzy = false,
    String order = null,
    Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
    MyClass start = null)
{
    using (QueryBuilder qb = ResourceFinder.GetQueryBuilder()) {
        return qb.Find<MyClass>(condition, fuzzy, order, limit, start);
    }
}

public static List<MyClass> Get(
    List<MyClass> conditions,
    Boolean fuzzy = false,
    String order = null,
    Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
    MyClass start = null)
{
    using (QueryBuilder qb = ResourceFinder.GetQueryBuilder()) {
        return qb.Find<MyClass>(conditions, fuzzy, order, limit, start);
    }
}
```

**Is there a shorter way to define these higher level `Get()`s?**

This would be an great place to use some preprocessing; but C# is lacking. With a small handful of exceptions, they're all identical, aside from the *Type* "parameter." And the end goal is to have these nearly identical definitions be less of a copy/paste/replace effort -- which is admittedly not much work; it just feels silly.

Contextual info: Each of the classes in question inherits from an abstract `DataObject`. We do have control over the data access library, including the `DataObject` class, but the intention is to keep it a fairly agnostic, drop-in-able SQL-writing library. So, we can change it to some limited extent.

<sup>Note: I'm fully prepared to accept "there's no way to do what you want", "you're doing it wrong", or other "you're an idiot" as an answer from qualified individuals.</sup>

Comment: How much shorter do you expect this to get? You already have method chaining and optional parameters... As far as I can tell the only part of the code taking up a lot of space is the arguments list which you can't get rid of.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm idealistically hoping for something nearly equivalent to a preprocessing template/macro. Or a way for the DataObject superclass to hold these methods and for subclasses to "borrow" them in a single, brief line -- or no lines at all.

Comment: I think Reed provided that answer. That or something along those lines is the closest you're going to get in C# I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a generic base class with methods for this:

```
class SomeBase<T> where T : DataObject, new()
{
    public T Get(Guid id) where T : DataObject, new()
    {
        return Get(new T() { Id = id }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public List<T> Get(
        T condition,
        Boolean fuzzy = false,
        String order = null,
        Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
        MyClass start = null) where T : DataObject
    {
        using (QueryBuilder qb = ResourceFinder.GetQueryBuilder()) {
            return qb.Find<T>(condition, fuzzy, order, limit, start);
        }
    }

    public List<T> Get(
        List<T> conditions,
        Boolean fuzzy = false,
        String order = null,
        Int32 limit = Int32.MaxValue,
        MyClass start = null) where T : DataObject
    {
        using (QueryBuilder qb = ResourceFinder.GetQueryBuilder()) {
            return qb.Find<T>(conditions, fuzzy, order, limit, start);
        }
    }
```

If you then subclass this for your specific class factory type, you don't need retyping:

```
// This class will have "typed" versions for these factory methods
public class MyClassFactory : SomeBase<MyClass>
{
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to play around with this, and it's looking quite promising. Very cool.